# JAXWS Client Timeout on Jboss

Tags: java, jax-ws, jboss5.x, connection-timeout

how can i set timeout for JAXWS client, Im using Jboss 5.1.
I was trying to do this with

```
bp.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout", 100);
bp.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", 100);
```

but it doesn't works. It works fine  for standalone client.

When i tried to use

```
bp.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", 100);
```

I.ve got org.jboss.ws.core.WSTimeoutException: Timeout after: 100ms, but it is heppening after 300 (3*100 ms).

Can anyone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

While this looks likely to be an oversight on your part, The settings for JAX-WS timeouts might depend on the specific RI you're building on.

You could try these settings (they are paired to be used in pairs)

```
   BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT
   BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT
```

BindingProviderProperties should be from `com.sun.xml.internal.WS.client`

Or the strings

```
   javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout
   javax.xml.ws.client.receive timeout
```

All properties to be put on `getRequestContext()` in milliseconds.

BtW, how were you able to time the milliseconds without code :)?

Answer (score 0):

**JAXWS** use the **JAXB** for **marshalling** and **unmarshalling**.

In the container probably it's taking more time because it's `JAXContext` scanning your classpath.

If that's the case try eager initialization of JaxBContext:

> JBossWS may perform differently during the first method invocation of
>   each service and the following ones when huge wsdl contracts (with
>   hundreds of imported xml schemas) are referenced. This is due to a
>   bunch of operations performed internally during the first invocation
>   whose resulting data is then cached and reused during the following
>   ones. While this is usually not a problem, you might be interested in
>   having almost the same performance on each invocation. This can be
>   achieved setting the `org.jboss.ws.eagerInitializeJAXBContextCache`
>   system property to true, both on server side (in the JBoss start
>   script) and on client side (a convenient constant is available in
>   org.jboss.ws.Constants). The JAXBContext creation is usually
>   responsible for most of the time required by the stack during the
>   first invocation; this feature makes JBossWS try to eagerly create and
>   cache the JAXB contexts before the first invocation is handled.

http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/jboss-web-services/web-services-performance-tuning